# How does AMQP and RabbitMQ works at deep level?

Tags: networking, rabbitmq, protocols, amqp

### Prehistory

I am having a talk about AMQP and RabbitMQ in front of my colleagues tomorrow and I want to fill the gaps in my knowledge about how does the whole protocol plus communication work and I seem to fail to find suitable source to read. I've watched video of basics of AMQP presented by Clemens Vasters, Architect in Messaging Department of Microsoft (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODpeIdUdClc&t) and I wanted to ask you guys a bit questions about it.

### Questions

1. Are the protocol headers the identifiers of the protocols themselves or there are some mappings between ports and protocols
   where OS knows about?
2. At which point does the application knows that sent data is using AMQP? I mean AMQP is layered over some reliable stream transport
   protocol, so do HTTP is , but yet they say AMQP is faster than HTTP
   because of its purpose and its lower overhead? Does this "latency"
   comes from when data is passes from application layer to presentation
   layer, because how I understand it, until application layer both HTTP
   and AMQP can be somewhat equal, beside the size and the methods?
3. How does my OS knows about protocols? For instance Clemens is talking about methods defined by AMQP that are send over the network
   in order to know whats next. But where are these methods defined , how
   they are defined? How does my computer know what to do when POST
   method request is made in the context of HTTP, there must be some sort
   of lower level instructions that distinct POST from GET and etc.
4. Last but not least, lets say I have distributed systems architecture that needs broker ( RabbitMQ for instance ) when my
   applications are talking to rabbit do they have to use AMQP? If so how
   do I specify that? The client libraries do that for me?

### Conclusion

I know that there are a lot of questions but I tried to do my best making them easy to answer. The whole idea of those question is for me to understand how all this communication and protocols thing work at some basic level.

Comment: This is a bit too broad, don't you think?

Comment: No, because 80% of those questions can be answered with yes or no. If additional explanations are needed I will gladly read them, but they are not necessary..

Comment: @kuskmen none of your questions can be answered "yes" or "no".

Comment: HEre you can find all the info https://github.com/rabbitmq/internals/